# how to stop ms studio break and handle the exception come from the system?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging

Once the system or other services have exception the microsoft studio will pop out the debug dialogue. how to prevent them pop out?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToTurnOffdisableTheNETJITDebuggingDialog.aspx

> For an application that includes managed code, the common language
>   runtime will present a similar dialog to JIT-attach a debugger. The
>   registry key that controls this option is called
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting.
>
> If value = 0, prompt the user by means of a message box. The choices
>   are: Continue. This results in a stack dump and process termination.
>   Attach a debugger. In this case, the runtime spawns the debugger
>   listed in the DbgManagedDebugger registry key. If none, control is
>   returned, and the process is terminated. If value = 1, simply return
>   control. This results in a stack dump, after which the process is
>   terminated.  (No more dialog) If value = 2, spawn the debugger listed
>   in the DbgManagedDebugger registry key.

Open regedit and change the value for `DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting` to 1
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting`.

Comment: I still get Just-In Time Debuger. It would still pop out an error message. An unhandled exception  occurred in ....exe. Just-In-Time debugging his exception fail. I do not want to show this dialogue either.